# What differs when compiling software on Different OS release/kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, compile, zabbix

I'm trying to compile zabbix-agent for Ubuntu 16, 14, 12 and 10. 
Some have kernel 2.6 and 3.13 above etc.,

I was wondering if compiling it on Ubuntu 16 (Kernel 3.13) would work fine on all Ubuntu release (2.x kernels)? I already tested it and it can start fine, I wonder if it would break any functionality or crash?

And can I also know why official zabbix-agent binary is only 300 Kb in size but when I compile it, its above 2.5 Mb.

Comment: It might work, but each version of ubuntu is going to have versions of libraries which could cause problems.

Comment: Okay. Anyway to determine what libraries a binary depends on? In Control file of deb package, it shows what libraries it depends but not sure if that is all it ever depends.

Comment: You can use `ldd` on a file to see what shared libraries it requires

Comment: I did try ldd and readelf, it reported "not a dynamic executable" and for readelf "There is no dynamic section in this file." I insatlled 32 bit libs too. 
`file /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd
/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=####, not stripped`